# Gnucash with Dutch translation?

Tags: 14.04, language-support, translation

I want to use [gnucash](http://www.gnucash.org/). However I am not familiar with the English terminalogy regarding finance. Now I wanted to start gnucash with the Dutch translation, which I believe is available for 2 reasons. Firstly the gnucash site is also in [Dutch](http://www.gnucash.org/index.phtml?lang=nl_NL), and secondly when I look to the [wiki](http://wiki.gnucash.org/wiki/Locale_Settings#Changing_the_Language_on_Linux) regarding starting gnucash with a different language I see also the Dutch translation been specified.

The problem I have is that I cannot seem gnucash to startup with the Dutch translation using `LANGUAGE=nl_NL.UTF8 LANG=nl_NL.UTF8 gnucash`

Checking `locale -a`, I obtain:

```
C 
C.UTF-8 
en_AG 
en_AG.utf8 
en_AU.utf8 
en_BW.utf8 
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8 
en_GB.utf8 
en_HK.utf8 
en_IE.utf8 
en_IN 
en_IN.utf8 
en_NG
en_NG.utf8 
en_NZ.utf8 
en_PH.utf8 
en_SG.utf8 
en_US.utf8 
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM 
en_ZM.utf8 
en_ZW.utf8 
nl_AW 
nl_AW.utf8 
nl_BE.utf8 
nl_NL.utf8
POSIX
```

So why don't I get gnucash to startup with the Dutch language?

-edit-
I installed all the Dutch language packages by

> sudo apt-get install language-pack-nl language-pack-gnome-nl
>   language-pack-nl-base language-pack-gnome-nl-base

Still no success unfortunately. However when I now tried to startup gnucash using `LANGUAGE=nl gnucash` I didn't get the warning `The locale defined in the environment isn't supported. Falling back to the 'C' (US English) locale`. However gnucash was still in English.

-edit2- 
Output of `locale`

```
LANG=nl_NL.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=nl:en
LC_CTYPE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_TIME=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="nl_NL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_NAME=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=nl_NL.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 0):

The `gnucash-common` package appears to only have plain `nl` as a translation for Dutch. I am not sure why, but it appears that the loading of translations is not falling back to that as an option.

However, running `LANGUAGE=nl_NL.UTF-8 ANG=nl_NL.UTF-8 gnucash` in the terminal, does seem to work for me. Is one of these variables not set correctly in your environment? Are you missing a *language-pack* package that may be required for the translations to work in your language in gnucash? You may need `language-pack-gnome-nl-base` installed for it to work.

Comment: Well I also tried using ``LANGUAGE=nl LANG=nl gnucash`` but that didn't work either.

Comment: in response to your edit, I also did install `language-pack-gnome-nl-base` and all other Dutch languages packs however that did not help :-(

Answer (score 0):

Since gnucash is a GNU application, it uses the LANGUAGE variable.

```
LANGUAGE=nl gnucash
```

is what you want.

The reason why

```
LANGUAGE=nl LANG=nl gnucash
```

does not work is that LANG requires a valid locale name, which nl is not, so you broke your locale and it used the fallback language English.

Comment: I tried `LANGUAGE=nl LANG=nl gnucash` which gave me `The locale defined in the environment isn't supported. Falling back to the 'C' (US English) locale`. I also tried `LANGUAGE=nl gnucash` which gave me the same result `The locale defined in the environment isn't supported. Falling back to the 'C' (US English) locale`

Comment: @WG-: In that case the locale in your environment is broken. What does the `locale` command output?

Comment: see edit in openings post.

Comment: @WG-: Well, that looks correct. And no error messages? In that case I don't understand why `LANGUAGE=nl gnucash` didn't work. It worked for me. Btw, it might be important that the command is not preceeded by invalid LANG settings. Open a new terminal window and start with the correct command.

Comment: @WG-: It just struck me.. That `locale` output shows that your display language is Dutch already, so just starting with `gnucash` should give you Dutch - just as with all other programs.

Comment: I tried doing that. I restarted my laptop, and tried starting up using `LANGUAGE=nl gnucash` no effect. And you are correct, I tried setting my whole environment to Dutch, which worked perfectly for everything, however gnucash kept starting up in the English language... Really frustrating :(

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with gnucash - finally i found the solution in the wiki:

> Notes for Ubuntu users
>
> If the previous instructions don't works, please check the following items:
>
> if you have installed `localepurge` package, be sure that the locale you are using is not deleted after the installation of gnucash. To check this, reconfigure `localepurge`, and be sure to not include your locale in the list of the ones to be deleted
>
> `sudo dpkg-reconfigure localepurge`
>
> Then reinstall all gnucash packages:
>
> `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnucash gnucash-common gnucash-doc`

In my case (`LANG=de_DE`), the `de_DE` entry was already excluded, but additionally i had to exclude the `de` entries, too. So, you may have to exclude the `nl` entry from localpurge, too.